# DoesNotExist at /my-cart/ Product matching query does not exist

Tags: django

I am working on a django project. But an error occurs just after creating MyCartView. Please someone help me to resolve this error:

[Error screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfcrC.png)

[Error screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MZ8mw.png)

This is 'urls.py' of 'shop' app inside the project -

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *
from . import views
app_name = 'shop'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='productdetail'),
    path('add-to-cart/<int:product_id>/',
         AddToCartView.as_view(), name='addtocart'),
    path('my-cart/', MyCartView.as_view(), name='mycart'),

]
```

This is 'views.py' -

```
class ProductDetailView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'shop/product_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        url_slug = self.kwargs['slug']
        product = Product.objects.get(slug=url_slug)
        context['product'] = product
        return context


class MyCartView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'shop/mycart.html'
```

This is 'mycart.html' -

```
{% extends "shop/base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block body %}

<h1>Items in cart</h1>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Can you tell me please what mistake I made with image?

Comment: it is already in the link. (1) One can not *locally* try your solution, since one can not copy it; (2) it  is inaccessible to people with visual impairment; (3) people can not *search* for your question later when they face the same issue; (4) it takes more bandwidth to load the images, and is less convenient to see the picture because of all the links; (5) later if the image service stops, the images are no longer acessible.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem Ok I am sorry. I will copy code here.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's easy: first you need to create an object (using raw insert in database / using other Django admin site / etc), and only then you can `get` it. The error means there is not object with `slug=url_slug` in your database.

Comment: Product is in database. Using 'ProductDetailView' also works fine. But after creating 'MyCartView' it shows the error. I don't know why it occurs.

Comment: well may be the value in `url_slug` is incorrect? try to log it

Comment: I use sessions. Is problem related to sessions?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `<slug:slug>` path will also match parts like `my-cart/`. Therefore if you visit `my-cart/`, it will fire the *first* path.

You can rearrange the paths to:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('add-to-cart/<int:product_id>/', AddToCartView.as_view(), name='addtocart'),
    path('my-cart/', MyCartView.as_view(), name='mycart'),
    # use as last path ↓
    path('<slug:slug>/', ProductDetaiLView.as_view(), name='productdetail')
]
```

It however might be better to just make the patterns *non-overlapping*. You can do that for example with a `product/` prefix:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('add-to-cart/<int:product_id>/', AddToCartView.as_view(), name='addtocart'),
    path('my-cart/', MyCartView.as_view(), name='mycart'),
    # no overlap with add-to-cart/ and my-cart/ ↓
    path('product/<slug:slug>/', ProductDetaiLView.as_view(), name='productdetail')
]
```

Comment: I replaced  this: path('my-cart/', MyCartView.as_view(), name='mycart'), with path('basket/', MyCartView.as_view(), name='mycart'), but still same error.

Comment: @JasmeetPabla: you should *not* replace it, you should change the order of the paths. Changing it `basket/` will still cause the same error.

Comment: Ok I will try by changing the order.

Comment: I change order like this as you told:       urlpatterns = [
    path('', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    path('my-cart/', MyCartView.as_view(), name='mycart'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', ProductDetailView.as_view(), name='productdetail'),
    path('add-to-cart/<int:product_id>/',
         AddToCartView.as_view(), name='addtocart'),

]      Now it works fine. Thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @JasmeetPabla: the `<slug:slug>` should be at the bottom...